# Why is my entire list being used in a forloop search, when the list should iterate?

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops

I am conducting a search using Selenium in Python. I have a .csv file that has a list of cities. I am seeking to run the list of cities through my for loop, so that each time the loop runs, a different city is being searched. For example, the loop should run for "New York," and then restart for "Beijing.

However, when I run my for loop, the entire list is being used in the search. So, "New York""Beijing" is being searched. I suspect this might be an issue with how I loaded in my list, but I'm not sure exactly where the error is.

Relevant code:

```
##Loading in CSV
with open('/Users/yu/PycharmProjects/actualmsa.csv', 'r') as f:
    msas = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    if msas[0].startswith('"') and msas[0].endswith('"'):
        msas[0] = msas[1:-1]

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/yu/Downloads/chromedriver')

#For Loop
for msa in msas:
    driver.get('https://google.com')

   inputmsa = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="search_areas"]')
   sleep(0.5)
   inputmsa.click()

   inputmsa.send_keys(msa)
```

Example of CSV contents:

```
Beijing
New York City
London
```

Comment: Please show me example of CVS contents.

Comment: Edited with the CSV contents example

Comment: I've run the code without driver, it works well. You can try just printing in for loop.